# I have problem with adding my object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So after creating an object,I want to add it to an array but seem it doesn't working
Only the last one was added and it looped.

I expect the output of `mang[0]` would be `('Samsung S8','s0','$200')` but it doesn't.

It only show the last one `('Samsung A60','s2','$400')`. It's the same to `mang[1]`.

```
var mang=[];
 var Phone = {
            Name:'',
            Img:'',
            Price:'',
            them :function(name,img,price){
                this.Name=name;
                this.Img=img;
                this.Price=price;
                mang.push(Phone);
            }
        };
Phone.them('Samsung S8','s0','$200');
Phone.them('Samsung S10','s1','$300');
Phone.them('Samsung A60','s2','$400');
```

Comment: `this`, in `them`, is always the same. The intent of your design isn't clear, it seems random. Maybe you want classes ?

Comment: Could you please tell me more detail about it?

Comment: Maybe this? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190097/whats-the-best-way-to-create-javascript-classes

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752868/does-javascript-have-classes

Comment: Thank you
I understand why my code doesn't work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please try this solution

```
var PhoneList = [];
function Phone(Name,Img,Price){
    this.Name = Name; 
    this.Img = Img;
    this.Price = Price ; 
}


Phone.prototype.addToArray = function(){
    PhoneList.push(this); 
}

let phone1 = new Phone('Samsung S8','s0','$200');
phone1.addToArray();
let phone2 = new Phone('Samsung S10','s1','$300');
phone2.addToArray();
let phone3 = new Phone('Samsung A60','s2','$400');
phone3.addToArray();

console.log(PhoneList);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks . Other way is you can use class. However I prefer function constructor over the class.

Answer (score 0):

What you could consider is escapsulating that functionality in a `class`, where you can have a list of phones that you add to with one method (`add`), and another (`logPhones`) to log the list of phones that have been added.

```js
class Phones {
  constructor() {
    this.phoneList = [];
  }
  add = (name, img, price) => {
    const phone = { name, img, price };
    this.phoneList.push(phone);
  }
  logPhones = () => {
    console.log(this.phoneList);
  }
}

const phones = new Phones();
phones.add('Samsung S8','s0','$200');
phones.add('Samsung S10','s1','$300');
phones.add('Samsung A60','s2','$400');
phones.logPhones();
```