# Methods to access private functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I hava a simple **js** function

```
var myFunction=function(){
    var age=20;
    this.name="bar";
    var show=function(){
        console.log(age);
    }
}
```

and creating an **instance** like:

```
 var obj=new myFunction();
 console.log(obj.show())
```

**logs:**[image: this]

how can **I resolve it??** I have tried to search SO for this but could not find    my solution.
**UPDATE**
I want all private members to remain same.

Comment: `show` is not a member of `obj`. It's a local variable of `myFunction`.

Comment: make `var show` into `this.show` so it is accessible on the instance of myFunction

Comment: Why are you doing `console.log(obj.show())`?  Doesn't `show()` *already* call `console.log()`?

Comment: but I want private member

Comment: @Anonymous: Then you can't call out *outside* of the function.

Comment: I think the point is to make that function private i.e. not accessible outside the object itself.  If so, to access it you'd need to do so within a method on that object.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that the `show` method is not accessible outside the function scope of `myFunction`.

In Javascript, the scope is defined within the function (Ignoring ES6 block scope). So, the scope of variables `age`, `name`, `show` is within the function. However, when you use `this` and use the constructor function (`new`) the newly created object contains the property which are associated with the `this` keyword. In your case, you associate only the `name` property with the new object and did not associate the `show` function with `this`.

One of the solution is using the **Module** Pattern. You can make the public accessible property by returning an Object which encapsulates the publicly exposed properties. So, in your case, you can expose `name` and `show` methods from the `myFunction`. Also, no need to do console.log twice. You can get the output by `obj.show()`. Otherwise it will log `undefined` as `show` function doesn't return anything.

```js
var myFunction=function(){
    var age=20;
    var name="bar";
    var show=function(){
        console.log(age);
    }
    
    return {
      name : name,
      show : show,
    }
}

 var obj=new myFunction();
 obj.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to

```
var myFunction=function(){
var age=20;
this.name="bar";
this.show=function(){
console.log(age);
}
}
```

Changing your show var to be a property

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution would be to make the function publicly accessible as an object property:

```js
var myFunction = function() {
  var age = 20;
  this.name = "bar";
  
  this.show = function() {
    console.log(age);
  }
}

var obj = new myFunction();
obj.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

With var you declared `show` as a variable and not a member of `myFunction`.
The same with `age`, if it is a class member, you should also use `this`

This one way to change it:

```js
var myFunction = function() {
    this.age = 20;
    this.name="bar";
    this.show = function() {
        console.log(age);
    }
}

var obj = new myFunction();
console.log(obj.name);
obj.show();
```

Find further information here: [best approach to member variables in object-oriented javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436234/best-approach-to-member-variables-in-object-oriented-javascript)