# Benefits/Drawbacks of declaring a constructor function

Tags: javascript

I am new to prototyping and constructor functions in JavaScript. I saw someone declare a constructor function in this way:

```
var Person = (function(){
    function Person(name, age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    Person.prototype.setName = function(name){ this.name = name; }
    Person.prototype.setAge = function(age){ this.age = age }

    return Person;
}());
```

Is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Thanks for the edit David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the correct form, but not the only one. This is an equivalent to:

```
function Person(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.setName = function(name){ this.name = name; }
Person.prototype.setAge = function(age){ this.age = age }
```

The code you presented wraps class declaration in one namespace, which is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

That works fine.  That code declares the constructor function that way because it wants to keep the code related to a `Person` in its own 'scope' or 'namespace', using an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) that defines the actual constructor function and its prototype methods.

In general, to create a constructor function, you just need:

1. A function
2. Inside the function used as a constructor, use 'this' to modify the object being created
3. call that function with the `new` operator

So, really, just doing:

```
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
Person.prototype.setName = function(name) { this.name = name; }
Person.prototype.setAge = function(age) { this.age = age; }

var me = new Person('Tom', 38);
```

is all you need for your example.  The IIFE scoping and returning the constructor function is just one way to create a type of 'module' for the Person type.

Answer (score 1):

What others fail to mention is that within your IIFE all functions turn into closures, you can use that for shared private or protected members.

[Pseudo-classical inheritance with privacy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799353/pseudo-classical-inheritance-with-privacy/21800194#21800194)

Since you're not using closure variables in the sample it's kind of useless to wrap it in an IIFE unless you like it for esthetic reasons.

More on prototype here:[Prototypical inheritance - writing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711)

Comment: the post you linked to "Prototypical inheritance - writing up", seems like a real great place to read on the topic. Thanks for the link :)