# How can I create encapsulated 'classes' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, encapsulation

In JavaScript, classes are usually emulated through constructors. However, I'm curious as to how one can create an *encapsulated* class, i.e. a class that keeps some of it's members private.

The commonly seen way of creating a 'class' is as follows:

```
function MyClass(parameter) {
    this.value = parameter;
}

MyClass.prototype.myPublicFunction = function() {
    console.log("About to run private function.");
    myPrivateFunction();
};

MyClass.prototype.myPrivateFunction = function() {
    ...
};
```

As you can see, in this example `myPrivateFunction` is actually public. One approach I've seen to solve this problem is the following:

```
function MyClass(parameter) {
    this.value = parameter;

    this.myPublicFunction = function() {
        console.log("About to run private function.");
        myPrivateFunction.call(this);
    }

    function myPrivateFunction() {
        ...
    }
}
```

This works; `myPrivateFunction` is inaccessible from the outside. But this approach has a problem - all functions in this 'class' are going to be copied across instances, instead of shared through the `prototype`. Also using `privateFunction.call(this)` everywhere isn't awesome.

Same goes for non-function members. How can I define a private instance-member in a class? What is the best and what is the most common approach? Is it acceptable to simply rely on a naming convention (such as beginning private function names with a `_`)?

Comment: There is basically no way to do this properly in ES5. You can do it with [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) in ES6 but that would mean you can only support very recent browsers.

Comment: James - Could you post a example with it (an answer?). I am not fully aware of the features in ES6 and got a bit curious about how a WeakMap could be used to deal with this. Guess I am growing rusty =)

Comment: Maybe the following will help, it has a protected instance specific pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21800194/1641941

Answer (score 2):

You could create a scope to hide you private functions with an auto executing function.

Like:

```
(function(){
    function myPrivateFunction(arg_a, arg_b) {
        /* ... */
        console.log("From priv. function " + this.value);
    }
    window.MyClass = function(parameter) {
        this.value = parameter;

        this.myPublicFunction = function() {
            console.log("About to run private function.");
            myPrivateFunction.call(this, 'arg_a', 'arg_b');
        }

    }
})();
```

But then you need to use `MyClass` only after it is declared since now it is an function expression and not a function statement, but all instances of `MyClass` will share the same instance of `myPrivateFunction`. but you will need to use `Function.prototype.call` (as in `myPrivateFunction.call(this, 'arg_a', 'arg_b');` to get the value of `this` keyword to match your instance.
If you do just `myPrivateFunction('arg_a, 'arg_b');` the keyword `this` will point to the global object (`window` on browsers) or `null` if `'strict mode'` is enabled.

Just a note: In my own code I don't do this but rely on naming conventions like `MyClass.prototype._myPrivateFunction = function(){};` when not using some framework.