# Is it possible to access private class attribute from its prototyped method in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this private class attribiute and I want to change its value in prototyped method. But "privateVariable" is not visible in "increment" method. How can I access this attribute from this method?

```
var myClass = function(){
    var privateVariable = 1
}

myClass.prototype.increment=function(){
    privateVariable++
}
```

Mind you that it is a private attribute.

Comment: You cannot. Notice that there are no classes, no attributes, and no privacy in JavaScript. You've got a *local variable* there.

Comment: Maybe a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/436120/218196 . @BartekKosa: Be nice.

Comment: @Felix Kling yes, much better. Being nice is for losers, remember this.

Comment: @BartekKosa What are you trying to actually accomplish? maybe's there's a better solution than what you're wanting here

Comment: @BartekKosa It's actually for people who choose to follow the rules here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @jdphenix I want private variable that can't be accessed from outside and I need it in method which is prototyped.

Comment: @BartekKosa: As we already told, that's simply impossible. jdphenix wanted to know *why* you would need that. What is the goal you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Bergi it is possible, look here http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2014/01/21/private-instance-members-with-weakmaps-in-javascript/

Comment: @BartekKosa: Better use symbols then ("private" properties) if you consider ES6 - you should've mentioned that in your question.

Comment: @Bergi I don't care if it is ES6 or ES5 when it is working with decent browser. I have a year to accomplish my project and than I will worry about that.

Comment: You assumed that you know better. My question was specific not like your duplicates. And I got mine answered unike your duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

`var` is a function-scoped variable declaration and is therefore inaccessible outside of its function (in this case, the `myClass` function). Two approaches to your problem would be either making the variable public by using `this.privateVariable = 1` or using a closure with access to the variable. Here's a simple example of the latter:

```js
function MyClass(){
  var privateVar = 1;
  this.incrementPrivateVar = function(){
    return privateVar++;
  }
}
var instance = new MyClass();
instance.incrementPrivateVar();
```

`incrementPrivateVar()` also returns the value of the private variable, but that can be prevented by simply removing `return` from that function.

---

If you're using ES6, there is a new, better way of creating and accessing private data that is essentially bulletproof: `WeakMap`. This is the example above in ES6:

```js
let privateData = new WeakMap();
class MyClass {
  constructor(data) {
    privateData.set(this, data);
  }
  getData() {
    return privateData.get(this);
  }
}
let instance = new MyClass({
  data1: 1,
  data2: 2
});
instance.getData();
```

Although you can inspect the contents of `privateData` in the console, within the script, you need to have the correct, specific instance of `MyClass` to access the data in `privateData`. To prevent anyone from having access to what's in `privateData`, you could simply wrap the `let instance = ...` in a block, preventing access to the `instance` variable, and therefore, the contents of `privateData`.

Comment: In you answer there is no prototyped method which I was asking about. I want this functionality but with prototyped method.

Comment: @BartekKosa Then I don't believe its possible to access `privateVar` outside of the constructor, because that is the intended behavior of a `var` declaration.

Comment: If you are sure about that you can post your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @BartekKosa According to [this](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html), my answer is the only viable method to do this in ES5. However, [this](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2014/01/21/private-instance-members-with-weakmaps-in-javascript/) shows how it can be done in ES6.

Comment: this link http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2014/01/21/private-instance-members-with-weakmaps-in-javascript/ answers my question, thank you.

Comment: Post your answer with weakmap example because it is working and it answers my question perfectly. I will accept it.