# JavaScript: Private members overwritten by another instance

Tags: javascript, private-members, prototyping

I have this:

```js
var Foo = function( v )
{
  /* Private member for shorthand prototyping */
  var _prototype = Foo.prototype;

  /* Private member */
  var _v = null;

  /* Public getter */
  _prototype.vGet = function( )
  {
    v = _v;
    return v;
  };

  /* Private setter */
  var vSet = function( v )
  {
    _v = v;
  };

  /* Constructor closure */
  ( function( v )
  {
    vSet( v );
  } )( v );
};

var f1 = new Foo( 10 );
console.log( 'f1::' + f1.vGet( ) );  /* f1::10 */
var f2 = new Foo( 20 );
console.log( 'f2::' + f2.vGet( ) );  /* f2::20 */
console.log( 'f1::' + f1.vGet( ) );  /* f1::20 */
```

So my problem is obvious. After creating the second instance of `Foo` in `f2`, `f1._v` is changing, too.

I choose this pattern with private setters to prevent members to be changed unwanted from outside the class itself.

By what I read about the prototyping this behaviour should not occur. But oviously my private member is used uniquely by several instances. So what did I misunderstood?

Comment: That's a private *static* member, actually. `this._v` would be an instance member.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436120/javascript-accessing-private-member-variables-from-prototype-defined-functions

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Every instantiation creates a new scope with independent private members. So these hidden members aren't static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Problem is that you redefine `Foo.prototype.vGet` every time you construct an new instance of `Foo`. The prototype is shared between all instances of `Foo`, but your redefined `vGet` function contains a reference the `_v` variable of the last constructed instance of `Foo`.

The solution is either to change `Foo.prototype.vGet = ...` to `Foo.vGet` and hence create a new function every time. Or to move the assignment outside of the constructor function and for example use `this._v` instead of `_v`, which weakens your encapsulation.

Comment: That's why all examples using the notation of defining prototype functions outside the constructor. But I missed the fact, that the prototype is on class and not on instance. And I tried to define it on instance. As you wrote it would weaken my encapsulation while I put my prototyping outside the constructor function, because I need to make <code>_v</code> public. So I decided to use <code>this.vGet()</code> instead. One benefit is that I'm able to use the prototype for inheritance for future purposes.