# Scope Regarding "use strict" and $this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
   "use strict";
   generalClass = function() {

   this.ip               = false; // page page
   this.ie               = false; // IE
   this.pp               = false; // portfolio page
   this.om               = false; // organize menu
   this.wc               = false; // shop
   this.sh               = false; // side header

   // So we can get the correct $this if needed
   $this               = this;

   this.__init();

} 

generalClass.prototype = {

   __init: function( $check ) {

    // Run functions
    $this.__format();
    $this.__resize(); 
   }
}
});
```

But I am getting that `$this` is undefined. I have tried writing it as var $this but still it is undefined for `$this.__format();`. I realise that I can use this instead of `$this`, but there are instances later in the code where I can't. How do I make it so that `$this` is defined in the `__init()` function? So that it refers to generalClass.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript - accessing private member variables from prototype-defined functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436120/javascript-accessing-private-member-variables-from-prototype-defined-functions)

Comment: Check this answer related to **"use strict"** mode: 
[What does “use strict” do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11496488/2247494)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it)

Comment: @jherax This doesn't have anything to do with strict mode.

Comment: I assumed it had something to do with use strict as the code was working perfectly fine before i added use strict.

Comment: @Juhana Of course yes! "use strict" avoid the access to global object, also when creating constructors, a exceptions is raised when no used the `new` operator to created the instance. Also you cant create global variables without `var` keyword.

Comment: It *looked like* it was working "perfectly fine", but you actually had only one global variable that was shared by all instances, and possible other classes that also used the same global variable.

Comment: @jherax The problem is still the same whether you're in strict mode or not. Strict mode only throws an error instead of letting the dev shoot themselves in the foot.

Comment: **"use strict"** does not allow you to use the `$this` if it was not declared in the outer/global scope with the keyword `var`. Also if you call `generalClass` without the `new` operator, the `this` inside the function will not work.

Comment: But I'm doing all that stuff. Shouldn't var $this be available to the __init function?

Comment: Show the code with which you call `generalClass` and the code where you declare `$this`, preferably all in one code block with what you already provided.

Comment: @JohnnySimpson No. Read the duplicate I linked earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you want to use strict-mode, then you have to put `var` (or `let`, or `const`) before your `generalClass` and `$this`.

Like that:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var generalClass = function() {

        this.ip               = false; // page page
        this.ie               = false; // IE
        this.pp               = false; // portfolio page
        this.om               = false; // organize menu
        this.wc               = false; // shop
        this.sh               = false; // side header

        // So we can get the correct $this if needed
        var $this             = this;

        this.__init();
    };

    generalClass.prototype = {

        __init: function( $check ) {
            console.log('$this', $this);
            // Run functions
            $this.__format();
            $this.__resize();
        }
    }

    var instance = new generalClass();
}());
```

(I changed `$(document).ready()` to IIFE so I could run it in console. Plus, I created instance of your class.)

What happens now? `$this` inside `__init()` is not defined. You would have to define `$this` inside `__init()` but here is the problem: what should be assigned to it?

In your example of `__init()` you could actually call `this` instead of `$this` but as you already pointed it’s not always possible.

But let me illustrate it with more abstract example:

```
(function () {
    var GeneralClass = function () {
        this.foo = [1, 2, 3];
        this.bar = 4;
        this.baz = [5];
    };

    GeneralClass.prototype.someFunction = function () {
        console.log('foo', this.foo); // [1, 2, 3]
        console.log('bar', this.bar);

        var self = this; // storing reference to *this* (oobject for later)

        this.baz.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log('baz?', this.baz); // undefined, because *this* means here this.baz, and there is no this.baz.baz
            console.log('baz!', self.baz); // [5]
        });

        console.log('foo * bar');
        this.foo.forEach(function (item, index) {
            console.log('item', index, 'value', item * self.bar);
        });

        console.log('Both accesible here', this.bar, self.bar);
    };

    var generalClassInstance = new GeneralClass();
    generalClassInstance.someFunction();
}());
```

Here I assign `this` to `self` (personally, I’d use `$this` for `$(this)` but it’s only a convention so do as you please, as long as you are consistent). Now functions called inside my function can use `self` which works as a reference to outer `this`. And if I called another function in my sub-function, it would still point to `GeneralClass`’s `this`.

I hope this is what you were primarily interested in.