# How to share same scope variables between different JS files

Tags: javascript

I have three script files. main.js, script1.js, script2.js.

The main.js just include that scripts into the document:

```
function IncludeJs(sFileName) {
    document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + sFileName + '"></script>');
}

IncludeJs("../script1.js");
IncludeJs("../script2.js");
```

The script1.js and script2.js code is under same namespace.

script1.js:

```
var sharedNamespace = sharedNamespace || {}; 

(function () {

    "use strict";

     function func1(){
        ....
     }

}).apply(sharedNamespace );
```

script2.js:

```
var sharedNamespace = sharedNamespace || {}; 

(function () {

    "use strict";

     function func2(){
        return func1();
     }

}).apply(sharedNamespace );
```

The func2 is not working because func1 is undefined. How i can put script1.js and script2.js under same scope with shared variables?

The solution of `sharedNamespace.func1 = function(){}`, is worst for me, because i don't want to expose this function to client who use my library...

Comment: It's impossible with the requirements posed. You either need to expose the function to everybody or you need to have a single script. There is no way to have a function both private and shared with a different script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript - accessing private member variables from prototype-defined functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436120/javascript-accessing-private-member-variables-from-prototype-defined-functions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...i don't want to expose this function to client who use my library...

If you're going to have separate script files and you want them to define functions that call each other, you have no choice. It's impossible to have `script1.js` and `script2.js` share a common scope that isn't also accessible to other scripts on the page.

Instead, you'll probably want to have the separate files you use for development combined for deployment, because a single script can (of course) have private information. (Private unless the user edits the script, of course.)

So for instance, you might have something like this:

`script1.js`:

```
var internal = internal || {};
(function(i) {
    i.func1 = function func1() {
        // ...code here, possibly using i.func2()
    };
})(internal);
```

`script2.js`:

```
var internal = internal || {};
(function(i) {
    i.func2 = function func2() {
        // ...code here, possibly using i.func1()
    };
})(internal);
```

When doing development, you include them separately and so any code could use `internal.func1`. But then when doing your all-in-one-script build, you'd have it wrapped

```
(function() {
    // ...contents of script1.js here...
    // ...contents of script2.js here...
})();
```

Now, `internal` is private to the combined script.

That's off the top of my head; there are probably less cumbersome ways...

Comment: Great! Thank's T.J